# Is there a way to LiveEdit on PhpStorm 2022?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

So in PhpStorm there is a way to debug live with a Chrome extension. However JetBrains recently decided to remove the Chrome extension from the Chrome store. So is there still a way to live edit in PhpStorm?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/live-editing.html. You do not need Chrome plugin for this for quite long time now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Live Edit](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/live-editing.html) is still supported, you don't need Chrome extensions to make it work.

Note also that since 2021.2 PhpStorm [supports](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2021/05/webstorm-2021-2-eap-1/#browser_pages_reload_on_save) pages auto-reloading on Save/editing while previewing, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/editing-html-files.html#ws_configure_auto_reload